# Jetpack Compose - UI not updating when flow is changed

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following Composable view and view model. The problem I'm having is that even though `isLoading` is being updated in the view model, it's not updating the view at all, it's stuck on the `LoadingUi`.

```
@Composable
fun MediaDetailsPage(
    mediaId: Long?,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit, block = {
        viewModel.fetchDetailsOf(mediaId!!)
    })
    val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()
    val isError by viewModel.error.collectAsState()
    when {
        isLoading -> LoadingUi()
        isError || viewModel.model == null -> ErrorUi()
        else -> MediaDetailsUi(viewModel.model!!)
    }
}

class MovieDetailsViewModel(
    private val useCase: MovieDetailsUseCase = config.movieDetailsUseCase
) : DetailsViewModel() {

    override fun fetchDetailsOf(id: Long, dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher){
        if(model != null) return
        fetchFrom({ useCase.getMovieDetailsOf(id) }, dispatcher)
    }
}

abstract class DetailsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading
    private val _error = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val error: StateFlow<Boolean> = _error
    var model: MediaDetailsModel? = null
    
    abstract fun fetchDetailsOf(id: Long, dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO)
    
    protected fun fetchFrom(
        useCaseCall: suspend () -> Either<MediaDetails?, ErrorEntity?>,
        dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    ) {
        job( {
            _isLoading.value = true
            val result = useCaseCall.invoke()
            if (result.isSuccess) model = result.body!!.convert()
            else _error.value = true
            _isLoading.value = false
        }, dispatcher)
    }
}
```

The most confusing thing is that I'm doing pretty much identically this elsewhere in the app and that is working perfectly. I was under the impression that a composable view refreshes when a flow variable is updated, or have I got the wrong end of the stick here?

Comment: Can you try putting a log after `_isLoading.value = false` to verify if this part is ever reached?

Comment: Yes it is reached. It just never goes back into the composable method

Comment: I'm also struggling. Seems like `collectAsState()` is not working properly